# como cambiar el borde de un commandButton con css?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

Estoy trabajando con primefaces y quiero redondear mis botones, pero no toma el css, como le puedo hacer, o cual es la forma correcta
Tengo el siguiente codigo

```
<h:head>

 <style type="text/css">
        boton {
           border-radius: 5px;

        }
    </style>

</h:head>
<h:body>
    <h:form>              

        <br></br>
        <h:panelGrid id="panelButtons" columns="3" style="text-align:center;" width="90%">   
            <p:commandButton id="boton" value="Empleados"   styleClass="ui-priority-primary" update="dlg1" oncomplete="PF('dlg1').show();" />
        </h:panelGrid>
```

Comment: Prueba con border-radius: 5px !important;

Comment: tampoco lo toma

Comment: el que yo uso para redondearlo es styleClass="button-16 b-greylight-16" pero no se si te parezca el estilo

Comment: que pasa si es en tus estilos agregas por ejemplo uno asi: .boton_redondeado{border-radius: 5px;} y luego dejas styleClass de la siguiente manera: styleClass="ui-priority-primary boton_redondeado".

Comment: ya quedo, lo estaba llamando mal, en lugar de llamarlo por el id=boton, era con el styleClass="ui-priority-primary, gracias

Comment: @Root93 Podrias ponerlo como respuesta para que cuando alguien mas tenga el problema pueda consultar

Answer (score 2):

Hay un error en tu selector de CSS. Esto es lo que tienes:

```css
boton {
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

Y esto es lo que deberías tener:

```css
#boton {
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

El numeral (#) indica que tu selector debe funcionar para los elementos que tengan el atributo ID con el valor "botón", que es justamente lo que tienes en el `<p:commandButton>`.

Ten presente también que JSF puede agregar un prefijo al atributo ID de los elementos cuando estos están dentro de un `<h:form>`, un `<ui:repeat>`, entre otros. En este caso lo más fácil es usar un selector por clase en lugar de uno por ID. Tu código quedaría así:

```
<h:head>
    <style type="text/css">
        .boton {
            border-radius: 5px;
        }
    </style>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <h:form>              
        <br></br>
        <h:panelGrid id="panelButtons" columns="3" style="text-align:center;" width="90%">   
            <p:commandButton value="Empleados"   styleClass="boton ui-priority-primary" update="dlg1" oncomplete="PF('dlg1').show();" />
        </h:panelGrid>
```